# How to convert .glade file to python class?

Tags: python, gtk, pyqt, pygtk

I'm learning the Python and now I'm trying to choose cross-platform-GUI-framework. As I see, the **PyGTK** is the best one, which fits my goals completely.

The only question: is there any analog of **pyuic4** (which creates python class based on .ui file created by QtDesigner) for files made with **Glade** app? Or the only way is creating class manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user interfaces create with glade are saved as xml file: using gtkbuilder, this file can be used with many programming languages, like c++ or python.
Pygtk lets you create application with user interfaces, based on glade file.But you have to do all by hand.

Comment: yes, I know what __Glade__ is =) I just want to understand, can I transform *.glade file to python class, as it implemented in PyQt with pyuic4.

Comment: if I need to create all class by hand, can you please share a link to manual? I would very appreciate that.

Comment: this is a simple [tutorial page](http://www.pygtk.org/articles/pygtk-glade-gui/Creating_a_GUI_using_PyGTK_and_Glade.htm)

Answer (score 4):

PyGtk is deprecated, you can use GObject in python/python3.

For a basic tutorial, see here: https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: I know that it has been deprecated, but still someone mind find that useful. :) No offence.

Answer (score 2):

For the sample of use of pygtk and glade you can see this stackoverflow question

[Python unity indicator applet and glade child window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643810/python-unity-indicator-applet-and-glade-child-window). Hope this gives you rough idea.