# Python unity indicator applet and glade child window

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

I have created an unity indicator applet with python and glade. Here is the screenshot that appears when indicator applet is clicked. You can see the preferences menu. When this preferences menu is clicked, it opens a new window.

`Indicator Applet Menu`
[image: Indicator Applet Menu]

`Preference Window`
[image: Preference Window]

Now the problem is when I click on close button, the whole application exists.

The code that triggers the preference window is as shown below :

```
def action_preferences(self, widget):
    '''
    Show the preferences window
    '''
    base = PreferenceWindow()
    base.main()

    self.menu_setup()
```

**preference.py** has the following code :

```
import sys
import json
import pynotify

try:
    import pygtk
    pygtk.require("2.0")
except:
    pass
try:
    import gtk
    import gtk.glade
except:
    print("GTK is not Available")
    sys.exit(1)

class PreferenceWindow:
    ui = None
    configs = {}
    notify = None
    window = None

    def __init__(self):

        if not pynotify.init ("nepal-loadshedding"):
            sys.exit (1)

        self.ui = gtk.glade.XML("pref_ui.glade")

        # Get the preference saved previously
        self.configs = self.parse_configs()

        saved_group_value = str(self.configs.get("GROUP"))

        self.ui.get_widget("text_group_number").set_text(saved_group_value)

        dic = {
            "on_btn_pref_ok_clicked":self.on_save_preference,
            "on_btn_pref_close_clicked":self.on_close,
            "on_preference_window_destroy":self.on_quit,
            }

        self.ui.signal_autoconnect(dic)

        if self.window is None:               
            self.window = self.main()

    def parse_configs(self):
        self.configs = json.load(open("config.txt"))
        return self.configs

    def save_configs(self, key, value):
        self.configs[key] = int(value)
        json.dump(self.configs, open("config.txt", "wb"))
        return True

    def on_save_preference(self, widget):
        group_number = self.ui.get_widget("text_group_number").get_text()
        self.save_configs("GROUP", group_number)

        # try the icon-summary case
        if self.notify == None:
            self.notify = pynotify.Notification ("Nepal Loadshedding", "Group saved successfully to : " + group_number)
        else:
            self.notify.update("Nepal Loadshedding", "Group saved successfully to : " + group_number)
            self.notify.set_timeout(100)

        self.notify.show()
        print "Saved successfully"

    def on_close(self, widget):
        print 'close event called'

    def on_quit(self, widget):
        sys.exit(0)

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `sys.exit()` because it will make your entire application to terminate (as you can see). What you have to do is call [`gtk.main_quit()`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/gtk-functions.html#function-gtk--main-quit). When you click *close* button, you can destroy the window.

```
def on_close(self, widget):
    self.ui.get_widget("<window-name>").destroy()

def on_quit(self, widget):
    gtk.main_quit()
```

Additionally, you call two times `PreferencesWindow.main()` (one at the bottom of `__init__()` and the second time after instantiation, with `base.main()`), which in turn calls to [`gtk.main()`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/gtk-functions.html#function-gtk--main). You have to remove one of them or your application will get stuck on the second one.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have already changed the code. Actually I was looking a way to use preference kind of window that will be closed after its sole purpose. If you look at this gist https://gist.github.com/samundra/7637068 on line 97 you can see that I have initialized a preference window. I would like this winodw to be closed keeping the normal flow of program.

Comment: That code is the same you had posted here. When you call `base.main()`, the flow will stop there until you close the Preferences window. When that happens, `action_preferences` will finish and `base` will be destroyed as it is out of scope.

Comment: I have noted that you call `gtk.main()` twice. You have to call it **only once**. I have added that to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the changes. I will have look on it when I am home. Currently I in office.